# Simple jquery/javascript switch href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, href

I have this link:

```
<div name="top">
  <!-- some code -->
  <a class="myLinkToTop" href="#bot">Click</a>
  <!-- some code -->
<div name="bot">
```

I wish to change the `href` attribute when it's clicked. I'm using this script:

```
 <script>
   $(".myLinkToTop").click(function(){
     $("a.myLinkToTop").attr("href","#top");
   });
 </script>
```

But I have 2 problems:

- When I click the link its `href` changes, but the action sends me to the #top, instead of #bot.
- After that, I want the `href` to switch between #top and #bot. I don't know how to do that so I was thinking about changing my class value with "toggleclass()" but I don't think this is the best use for my problem.

Comment: Are you trying to go to the top of the page when that link is clicked?

Comment: No I wish to go #bot at first but after I will go normaly in #top if i click on the same link. Then when I have clicked on my link i can go back #bot etc..

Comment: I see, so you wish to toggle the two?

Comment: why not just alternate between the hrefs based on the current value? `if - else` ?

Comment: I wish to switsh the "href" attribute on this link each time I click on it. But when i try with my simple exemple the "href" attribute change but the location is also changing before I have moved. I don't know if you understand my english is not very good.

Comment: I have tried too but the location on the click in this link is not where it should be. The page load .. I click normaly I move into #bot then the href change but with this script I load my page then I click on this link but the link sent me to the #top always.I understand why but I don't know how to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will move to the current href on link and then change it:

```
$(".myLinkToTop").click(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.href = this.href;
    this.href = this.hash === "#top" ? "#bot" : "#top";
 });
```

Comment: @lll This first prevents the default handler for clicking the link executing, then moves to top or bottom, then checks if hash is #top change to #bot else set to #top.

Answer (score 1):

Like Banana said, you could use an `if/else` statement to check the current `href` value. If the current value is `#bot`, set it to `#top` after 1 second (that will allow the original value to go through first). And vice versa if the current value is `#top`.

```
$(".myLinkToTop").on("click", function () {
    var $this = $(this), // cache "this as a jQuery object"
        href = $this.attr("href");

    if (href === "#bot") { 
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.attr("href", "#top"); 
        }, 100);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $this.attr("href", "#bot"); 
        }, 100);
    }
});
```

Comment: $(this).attr("href"); - why not use this.href?

Comment: Thank you I understand this script better. I don't know if it is better but it is more easier to understand.